# Arrays and Lists in Bourne Shell

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

I have the code

```
read input
case "$input" in
    "list"* )
        blah
        ;;

    "display"* )
        blah
        ;;

    "identify"* )
        blah
        ;;

    "rules"* )
        perl image.pl $input[1]
        ;;

    "quit" )
        echo "Goodbye!"
        ;;

    * )
        echo -n "Error, invalid command. "
        ;;

esac
```

I'm trying to figure out how to pass the value of $input to image.pl without including the string "rules" in the input.

I.e, if a user enters 'rules -h' I want to just pass '-h' to image.pl.

Likewise with my other cases, I would like to specificity test if there have been any other arguments passed along in the input, e.g. for 'quit' I would like to test if a user said 'quit x' and throw a specific error that 'quit' does not accept any other "arguments".

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean Bourne shell or Bash?  The capabilities are radically different in this area.  Notably, Bourne Shell does not include arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using Bourne shell as the title specify:

```
read input
set -- $input
case "$1" in
   list)
      blah
      ;;

    rules)
      perl image.pl "$2"
      ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I will accept your answer in 3 minutes when it lets me.

Comment: You can also use the "shift" built-in command to remove the first element in the $1,$2,.. array. Then, just pass "$*" to the perl script ($* is the entire $1,$2,.. array). Bottom line is that sh supports only *one* array.

Comment: @nimrodm: you should prefer `"$@"` over `"$*"` unless you specifically want the shell to squash any special quoting.  Still you get my +1.

Comment: Thank you @nimrodm, I just literally just thought of this as a problem, that the solution given to me before was not quite what I needed as I still want to be able to pass the remainder of the commands. So thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$input` variable to initialize an array in bash, here is the code:

```
read input
declare -a arr=($input)
case "${arr[0]}" in
    "list")
        blah
        ;;
    "display")
        blah
        ;;
    "identify")
        blah
        ;;
    "rules")
        shift
        perl image.pl ${arr[1]}
        ;;
    "quit")
        echo "Goodbye!"
        ;;
    *)
        echo -n "Error, invalid command. "
        ;;
esac
```